# What is the best library for reading ID3 tags?

Tags: python, mp3, id3

What library is presently the most thorough and capable ID3 tag reading library available? Preferably something I can compile as a shared library and wrap with Python's `ctypes` library, or even a Python package.

Comment: You surely want to use `mutagen`. It is *the* python id3 tag library and does not need any external dependencies. However, in case you need/want to *write* ID3 tags be warned that it only writes ID3 v2.4 which is not as widely supported (*cough* windows explorer *cough*) as ID3 v2.3. http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/issues/detail?id=85 is the relevant feature request on their bugtracker in case you need write support.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've had a good time using [mutagen](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/) (tutorial: http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/wiki/Tutorial) - it's quite simple to get the info. Note that you should use the `Easy ID3` option.

```
>>> from glob import glob
>>> from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
>>> for filename in glob('/home/jon/Downloads/*.mp3'):
    mp3info = EasyID3(filename)
    print mp3info.items()


[('artist', [u"James O'Brien's Mystery Hour"]), ('title', [u"James O'Brien's Mystery Hour - 7 Dec 12"])]
```

Comment: Since Google Code closed down, here is the new source code link: https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen. The documentation can be read here: https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html.